# An object from printing dies

Tags: modeling, import

There's something i think blender can't do, in opposite to Cinema. But maybe you can prove me wrong (hopefully).

I have a product die cutting. I need to imitate this product in 3D. Is there a way to import die cutting into blender so it can create a solid from it?

[image]

Comment: Trace the image as paths in a vector drawing program (inkscape, illustrator etc), Export the image as SVG. Blender can import svgs as long as they are paths. Form there you can  convert it to a mesh and fold it however you want

Comment: Umm... i have it as vector, there's no problem with importing it as svg.

I need steps from importing to making a solid. 

How am i supposed to convert lines into mesh and how would it help?

Have you noticed the beveled cut at the side ? How am i supposed to fold it ?